# I am looking for cursive forms of the kanji for 'zu'. It means a drawing. Thanks.

Tags: kanji

I am looking for cursive forms , not standard, of the kanji for zu  'drawing'. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I strongly recommend you replace the 'zu' with the Kanji in question. Also, what, exactly, is your question/end purpose? We aren't a search service, but if there is a question about the cursive form you need to understand about, please feel free to include this as part of the body of your question. Good luck!

Comment: [図](https://api.nihongoresources.com//images/kanji/56/56f3.svg) ?

Answer (score 2):

This is how 図　is written in cursive form.

[image]

**Here's the stroke order:**

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Source: [草書にチャレンジ　図(圖)[zu]　Kanji cursive script](https://ryohkei.com/kanji-zu-cursive-19116.html)

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Did you create these images?  If not, can you please tell us where they came from?

Comment: @snailboat Sure. I forgot to add a link at the end. My bad.

Comment: @snailboat I just edited my answer and added the source.

Comment: It looks like step 2 of the stroke order is missing. It's available in the link but not in your answer.

Comment: @psosuna Sorry about my missing! I'll edit my answer and add that in!